# How to bind to all the number keys in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Is there any way to bind to all the number keys in Tkinter?

It should be equivalent to this:

```
frame.bind("0", my_handler)
frame.bind("1", my_handler)
frame.bind("2", my_handler)
...
```

I was hoping that I can find something like:

```
frame.bind("< num>", my_handler)
```

but apparently this does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a loop:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    frame.bind(str(i), my_handler)
```

(If using Python 3, substitute `range` for `xrange`.)